# Why is my RSA encryption algorithm not working correctly

Tags: java

According to formulas and searches for private / public keys, everything is correct for me. The problem is that I'm encrypting a picture, that is, an array of bytes. Everything is encrypted correctly, but the decryption no longer works, although the formula is the same. The problem is that when I start byte-by-byte encryption, for example, 1 byte is 255, it is encrypted into the number 1397715838 and then again encrypted into bytes into a file. Then I read the encrypted file again and the first byte will already be 255, not 1397715838. Thus, the entire decryption process will not work, because I did not understand how to get 1397715838 from the number 255.

```
public static void RSA() throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();

    var fileData = ReadFileToBinary("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\dino.png");

    FileOutputStream encryptFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\endino.png");
    FileOutputStream decryptFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\dedino.png");

    BigInteger P = BigInteger.probablePrime(16, random);
    BigInteger Q = BigInteger.probablePrime(16, random);

    BigInteger N = P.multiply(Q);

    BigInteger f = (P.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(Q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));

    BigInteger d;
    BigInteger c;

    BigInteger encrypt;
    BigInteger decrypt;

    do {
        d = new BigInteger(16, random);
    } while (!(d.gcd(f).equals(BigInteger.ONE)) && d.compareTo(f) < 0);


    c = d.modInverse(f);

    for (var mess : fileData) {
        BigInteger message = BigInteger.valueOf(mess);

        encrypt = cryptoLab1.ModPow(message,d, N); //ecnrypt 1397715838
        encryptFile.write(encrypt.toByteArray()); // encrypt byte here 255
    }

    var fileData2 = ReadFileToBinary("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\CryptoLab1\\src\\crypto\\endino.png");


    
    for(var mess: fileData2) {
        BigInteger message = BigInteger.valueOf(mess); //Need value here 1397715838, not 255
        decrypt = cryptoLab1.ModPow(message, c, N);
        if(decrypt.intValue() > 127) {
            decrypt = decrypt.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(256));
            decryptFile.write(decrypt.toByteArray());
        }
        else {
            out2.write(decrypt.toByteArray());
        }
    }
```

ReadFileToBinary:

```
public static int[] ReadFileToBinary(String path) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path);
    byte[] fileData = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    in.read(fileData);
    int[] arrayBytes= new int[(int) file.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
        arrayBytes[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(fileData[i]);
    }
    in.close();

    return arrayBytes;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you've identified the problem and answered your own question.  I'm not sure what your post is about then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is that `BigInteger.toByteArray()` return an array, which size depends on the value. As an example, for the value `42`, the returned byte array is `[42]` with a length of one. But for the value `1234567890L` the byte array is `[73, -106, 2, -46]` with a length of four. When you concatenate each encrypted byte input the output file, you have no marker where one original byte array ended and the next original byte array started. So when you read the bytes `[54, -2, 43, 4, 13, -140, ...]` you don't know if the first byte array to decrypt is with `[54]`, `[54, -2]` or `[54, -2, 43]` (or any other length).

One possible solution is to add a length information for each byte array you write into the encrypted result file. As an example, the result file byte content could look like this:

```
[2, 54, -34, 5, -34, 43, 1, 9, -11, 1, 5, 3, 76, -100, 81, ...]
 ^           ^                      ^     ^                 ^
 |           |                      |     |                 |
```

The arrows indicate the positions of the length information, following by the byte array values for that value to decrypt. The algorithm will look like this (pseudocode):

```
while (!file_end_reached) {
    read next byte for the length
    read X bytes depending on the length
    create BitInteger from byte array
    decrypt
}
```